# Python Addin only works if Python Window open in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-addin

Using ArcGIS 10.2.1 and Python 2.7

My python addin works in ArcMap if I open ArcMap with the Python window open, but if I open ArcMap without the Python window open - I get a "MISSING" tool error.  [image] See code below.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class IntersectionSearchCmb(object):
"""Implementation for IntersectionSearch_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""
def __init__(self):
    arcpy.AddMessage("HERE I AM 1")
    print "Here i am 1"
    cur,row = None, None
    self.street_list = []
    self.street_dict = {}
    self.street_list.append("Battle St at 6th Ave")
    self.street_list.append("6th Ave at Battle St")
    self.street_dict["Battle St at 6th Ave"] = [688855.366,5616889]
    self.street_dict["6th Ave at Battle St"] = [688855.366,5616889]
    self.street_list.sort()
    #self.street = list(set(self.street))
    self.items = self.street_list

    self.editable = True
    self.enabled = True
    self.width = 'WWWWWWWWWWW'
    self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW'
def onSelChange(self, selection):
    arcpy.AddMessage("HERE I AM 2")
    print "Here i am 2"
    self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
    self.df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(self.mxd)[0]

    try:
        x = self.street_dict[selection][0]
        y = self.street_dict[selection][1]
        extent = arcpy.Extent(x,y,x,y)
        self.df.panToExtent(extent)
        self.df.scale = 1500
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

    except:

        pass

def onEditChange(self, text):
    pass
def onFocus(self, focused):
    arcpy.AddMessage("HERE I AM 3")
    print "Here i am 3"
    self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
    self.df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(self.mxd)[0]
    pass
def onEnter(self):
    pass
def refresh(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Please add the text of the error message you are receiving.

Comment: I am not recieving an error message - just the tool within ArcMap is shown as [Missing].  No errors.  I have attached the screen shot of the error in the original question now.

Comment: I think your config.xml and ArcPy code may be out of sync.

Comment: Any ideas on how to test this?  I have re-compiled it, but perhaps I need to re-create it from scratch?

Comment: Does it work on another machine?  I have seen this before - addin icons showed on several computers and didn't show on several others.

Comment: I have tried numerous machines, and none seem to work, my personal PC does work, but I have done alot of customization, so it is hard to determine exactly why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question:  the file C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\desktop10.2.pth wasn't structured correctly.  It was missing these 3 lines:

*c:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\bin*

*c:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy*

*c:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Scripts*

Once these lines were added to the desktop10.2.pth file - everything worked correctly.  I think our Python was installed incorrectly. Thanks for all your suggestions!